# When ssh to remote host, how can I know the bash pid running on remote host?

Tags: bash, ssh, pid

When I ssh to a remote host, Is it possible that I get the remote bash pid in my local machine? or vice versa?

in local terminal, I simply do:

```
ssh user@remote.com
```

for example, I know the ssh pid in local machine:

```
ps faux
...
shunh    32683  0.1  0.0 121148  5116 pts/2    Ss   07:02   0:00  \_ -bash
shunh    33079  0.6  0.0 189360  8484 pts/2    S+   07:03   0:00      \_ ssh -X remote_host
```

and in remote_host:

```
ps faux
...
root     214679  0.0  0.0 158820  5724 ?        Ss   07:03   0:00  \_ sshd: shunh [priv]
shunh    214681  0.0  0.0 158820  2556 ?        S    07:03   0:00      \_ sshd: shunh@pts/1
shunh    214682  0.0  0.0 121124  3608 pts/1    Ss   07:03   0:00          \_ -bash
```

I wanna know if I can read the pid number "214682" in my local machine?

Comment: It's probably a good question can make a good impact, but you are asking it in the wrong place. SO does not allow such question here, There are other communities you should look to ask this question. You can ask on Server Fault. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Kiran. I'll post another thread there.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh user@remote.com 'echo $$'`

Refer to the Bash manual, [3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_0024):

> ***$***
>
> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

Comment: The challenge then is how do you communicate it back to the caller if your shel runs for an extended time and produces other output, too?

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use $$ in remote host to get its pid. But I need to know this from my local machine.

Comment: @tripleee write this pid to any file and then open another local shell to ssh to remote host to get it.

Comment: @donkey1120 why you want to get this pid? What are you trying to achieve? There may be simple solutions if more details are provided.